# Error: Unrecognized argument type to convert to an Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I am working with Sentinel-1 SAR data. I want to display each image (8 of them) separately onto the map.
Here is the basic filtering; s1 is image collection

```
var assamVV= s1
.filterBounds(roi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
  .filterMetadata('resolution_meters', 'equals' , 10)
  .select('VV');
```

//Filter by date

```
var beforeVV = assamVV.filterDate('2020-05-15', '2020-05-24');

function addImage(image) { // display each image in collection
image = ee.Image(image.id);
Map.addLayer(image);
}
```

I used the map function to display each image

```
beforeVV.map(addImage);
```

But to my dismay, it shows the following error:

```
Unrecognized argument type to convert to an Image: function standin(_0) {
    return newF.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

if I try `Map.AddLayer(beforeVV)`, it only displays single image as a mosaic. I want to display all of them individually.